# Zebra g420d - light flashes green but nothing is printed

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, zebra-printers, zpl, cups

I'm trying to print labels on a Zebra g420d printer, it's setup with CUPS and connected through USB to a Raspberry PI. It works excellent for printing PDF-labels so no problems with communication.

Now I create a secondary queue which is setup as a raw local printer in CUPS to print another type of labels, this time it's not PDF's, instead it's just ZPL. I print with the following command:

```
lpr -P <PRINTER_NAME> -o raw <FILENAME.zpl>
```

The green light flashes and file disappears from queue but nothing is printed. Things I have tried:

- Using ZPL-driver instead of raw
- Different very basic ZPL-labels, some directly from ZPL examples in documentation.
- Rendering the label on http://labelary.com/viewer.html, downloading file and send to printer
- ZPL with and without linebreaks after each command / at the end

I suspect something might be wrong with encoding of ZPL-commands so I enabled dump mode, here's a photo of the output with hex codes. Note that it's three tries after each other.

[dump mode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/543ew.jpg)

One of many ZPL-labels tried:

```
^XA^FO1,80,0^ADN,25^A0N,100,80,3214^FD123^FS^FO280,80,0^BY3^BCN,150,Y,N,Y,A^FD456^FS^XZ
```

CUPS Setup:

```
Description:    Zebra Technologies ZTC GK420d
Location:   
Driver: Local Raw Printer (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20GK420d?serial=28J2007020XX
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=unknown
```

Any ideas what the reason for this behaviour could be or what to try next?

Comment: What kind of linebreaks have you tried, only ``0x0A`` (``LF``) or also ``0x0D 0x0A`` (``CR LF``)?

Comment: Only `0x0A` (check the dump output above). I also tried the sample label from labelary.com without touching it but same behaviour. Does ZPL require `LF` or `CRLF` at end of file?

Comment: I use Windows based txt files including ZPL, so they use ``CR LF`` by default. I would give that a try...

Comment: `CR` or `CRLF` did not make any difference, a factory reset of the printer did though. It's performed this way: Hold down the forward feed button on the front panel. The indicator light will start a flash sequence: 1, 1-2, 1-2-3, and so on. When it flashes four times, release it. This resets the printer to factory defaults.

Comment: Whenever I printed from Windows, with ZPL, I'd always use the raw text based drivers. Is there one of those available?